# Getting EACCES (Permission denied) when tried to modify the file /sys/class/power_supply/battery/capacity in android device

Tags: android, adb

I have a requirement to change the battery level of an android device,with my app. So I tried modifying the "capacity" file in " /sys/class/power_supply/battery/" directory.
But when ran the code I see the following error:

**java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/class/power_supply/battery/capacity: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)**

Below is the code which I tried with to edit the file.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh /system/xbin/su");
FileWriter fw= new FileWriter(new File("/sys/class/power_supply/battery/capacity"));
fw.write("45");
fw.close();
```

Here is the Manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.test_app.qa">

<application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CACHE_FILESYSTEM"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
<instrumentation android:name="android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    android:label="test"
    android:targetPackage="com.test_app.module"/>
```

Can anyone suggest me with a way to modify the file

Comment: Always when asking on stackoverflow, post as much information as possible... show the class, the AndroidManifest, show the Logcat, show whatever you think is relevant... we can only help, if you shown the efforts you made, and give us details...

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have requested the permission to change/read files, and if the path is the correct one.

[By documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html)

> > public class FileNotFoundException
> >     extends IOException
>
> Signals that an attempt to open the file denoted by a specified pathname has failed.
>
> This exception will be thrown by the FileInputStream, FileOutputStream, and RandomAccessFile constructors when a file with the specified pathname does not exist. It will also be thrown by these constructors if the file does exist but for some reason is inaccessible, for example when an attempt is made to open a read-only file for writing.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply.. The file does exist in the location, but I get the ACCESS DENIED error. How can I get the permission to modify the files under /sys directory in a device.

Like when we add **<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> **this permission in Android Manifest file, we can modify the files under /data directory of the device.

Comment: Edit your question, post your manifest. EACCES  are usually related to lack of permissions.